# Alternative solution for executing a long running SP via a web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I need to tell the Database Handler that it should run a script which generates 300-500MB of data, then notify my C# application that the script has completed.

After that I need to get the newly created data to my C# application, manipulate it then send it to an FTP-server.

One way to do this would be to call the SQL-server via a web service, let the Database Handler run the script, then return the data. The C# application would then manipulate the data and finally send it by FTP. However because of the size of the data and the run-time of the script being around 1 hour this method is far from optimal.

Any suggestions on a better solution?

EDIT: I forgot to mention some important parts. SSIS was something I thought of as well. The problem is that the database is on a different server which doesn't have ports open for sending via FTP.

Answer (score 0):

I would implement this as a service.  Use the web service to allow users to request execution of the script (queue a request), but actually execute the script from the service (read the queue and perform the action).  You have far greater control of the entire data gathering and delivery process from within the service.

Answer (score 0):

My own strategy would be to develop a standalone application (installed on the server) to perform the data retrieval, manipulation and FTP transfer. This application could be executed by code in your ASP.NET application as a result of some user interaction perhaps, and could update the database as to its progress so that your user could have some feedback via the ASP.NET web interface (ajax polling or loading a status page).

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using SSIS?  One of the things it is really useful for is controlling data-centric multi-step workflows.